# Java - how to pass objects to implementation of KeyListener interface?

Tags: java, parameters, interface, keylistener

I am trying to implement a KeyListener interface. In implementation I want to do some stuff depending on the key code (keyPressed) with my "Player" object and a bunch lists, which are created in another class. Until now I was passing them as a parameter, but I now I can't change the "keyPressed" argument list. My only idea was to create a static fields representing the player and lists and access them by ClassName.staticField, but it's probably not the best idea. How can I access them in a more proper way?

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{
    int code = e.getKeyCode();
    //doing some stuff with code
    if(code == KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT)
        player.manipulateItem(/*few lists to pass here*/); //how to access the "player" object and lists?
}                                                           //they are created in another class as variables
```

Answer (score 0):

The best you pass the player in the constructor of your key listener but if its value can change add its container. Some exemple :

```
public class A extends JFrame{
    final Player currentPlayer;
    public A(){
        currentPlayer = new Player();
        add(new JLabel("press to increase player score");
        addKeyListener(new MyKeyListener(currentPlayer));
        a.pack();
        a.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static final class MyKeyListener extends KeyAdapter{
         Player player;
         public MyKeyListener(Player player){
             super();
             this.player = player;  
         }

         @Override
         public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
             int code = e.getKeyCode();
             //doing some stuff with code
             if(code == KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT)
                  player.manipulateItem(/*few lists to pass here*/);
             e.consume();
        }
    }
}
```

If your player is not final and can change pass the instance of A and use a getter. dont forget to consume your key event if your listener is the only target.
PS : sorry import are missing i don't have my IDE under the hand hopping their is no errors